# Manage iOS alert settings from within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

In my project I want to change application settings such as sound on/off  and vibrate on/off for chat notification(Local Notification).

The Settings view look something like this:

[image: App Settings]

How can I toggle between the sound and vibration from within the app.

I read in some S.O thread that the vibration is automatic with the local notification sound.

So in short I end up with this logic

> Sound On, Vibrate On - Set any sound file.
>
> Sound Off, Vibrate On - Set a silent sound file.
>
> Sound On, Vibrate Off - ??
>
> Sound Off, Vibrate Off - ??

How can I handle the last two situations?

Comment: Hey, I want the same functionality in my app. If you have found something helpful for this problem then please help me out too. :)

Comment: @AnuPadhye No luck...